# mpirun hangs when connected to wifi

Tags: mpi, osx-mavericks, openmpi

I am running mpirun (Open MPI) 1.8.5 on my Mac OSX 10.9, but when I try

`mpirun -np 4 run.exe`

the terminal just hangs and eventually I get an error message

`A process or daemon was unable to complete a TCP connection
to another process:
  Local host:    my_computer_name
  Remote host:   10.0.0.15
This is usually caused by a firewall on the remote host. Please
check that any firewall (e.g., iptables) has been disabled and
try again.`

Now, if I turn off my Wifi, everything works fine. Also, I do not have any firewall enabled. It's really annoying to have to turn off my wifi everytime I need to run mpi. Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting hostfile explicitly.

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm confused from the instructions on the web.

Comment: https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=running#mpirun-hostfile is a good example. I cannot do better.

Comment: Thanks. I added my hostname and it still hangs when I'm on wifi. I do `mpirun -np 4 --hostfile my_host_file run.exe`, but still no luck. Of course, when I turn my wifi off, it works fine.

Comment: Are you using your IP address, the DNS hostname or localhost?

Comment: whatever the out of `>>hostname` in my terminal. Which one is that?

Comment: Why don't you run the command yourself and share the answer? I cannot debug your machine's issues without sufficient information.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350173/why-does-mpirun-not-respect-my-choice-of-btl?rq=1). You need to tell MPI explicitely not to use the wifi, then it will survive disabling the wifi.

What happens is, that [MPI greedily uses all IP networks it can muster](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=tcp),
thus, when you disable wifi, MPI looses one of the IP connections it uses.